# Downloading GRIB GFS files with specific filters?

Tags: grib-2, noaa

Is it possible to download a smaller GRIB GFS file with specific parameters only (e.g. surface wind and temperature values) rather than hundreds of MB of data? If so, what is the usual approach to achieve this?

Comment: http://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/wesley/fast_downloading_grib.html

Comment: Thank you for the link. Although my eyes hurt of formatting and surfing around this website is utterly painful, I feel like I understand a bit more about filtering at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, after a bit more of search and after forgetting how I even ended up on this page, there is one very helpful (official) filtering page [right here on NOAA "website"](http://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/filter_gfs_0p25.pl?dir=%2Fgfs.2015120112). Combining "levels" with "variables" (all acronyms are described [here, also on official NOAA "NCEP Products Inventory" page](http://www.nco.ncep.noaa.gov/pmb/products/gfs/gfs_upgrade/gfs.t06z.pgrb2.0p25.anl.shtml)) I managed to filter the data.

Selecting "Show the URL only for web programming" checkbox on the bottom of the "filtering" page shows up the URL needed to download specific file, e.g.

```
URL=http://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/filter_gfs_0p25.pl?file=gfs.t12z.pgrb2.0p25.anl&lev_0-0.1_m_below_ground=on&lev_0.1-0.4_m_below_ground=on&var_TMP=on&var_UGRD=on&var_VGRD=on&leftlon=0&rightlon=360&toplat=90&bottomlat=-90&dir=%2Fgfs.2015120112
```

Comment: Note that you can't do arbitrary combinations - some variables don't have levels.