# How to extract specific information from GRIB files?

Tags: python, latitude-longitude, weather, grib-2, noaa

How to extract fetched GRIB data with Python and [gribapi package](https://software.ecmwf.int/wiki/display/GRIB/GRIB+API+examples) (link goes to official ECMWF Wiki)? I tried to follow few examples from their "documentation" and do it myself, but I just cannot figure out how to retrieve only specific parameter (e.g. surface temperature or wind) for given latitude and longitude. I don't need to plot the data or visualizations, I just need to pass few parameters when reading the file and get numbers back.

So far, I tried to download [original GRIB2 file from www.ftp.ncep.noaa.gov](http://www.ftp.ncep.noaa.gov/data/nccf/com/gfs/prod/gfs.2015121400/gfs.t00z.pgrb2full.0p50.f000) and run [few Python API example scripts from mentioned ECMWF Wiki](https://software.ecmwf.int/wiki/display/GRIB/GRIB+API+examples) page. Since Python API documentation doesn't exist, I have some hard time to understand which methods should I use in order to:

- read the file,
- select only specific "message" (e.g. surface temperature only) if there's more "messages" in a file,
- print out the value for a specific location (using `grib_find_nearest` method).

Example code which I have so far, mostly copied from ECMWF examples and this answer from [Getting time dimension from GRIB file?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/92195/getting-time-dimension-from-a-grib-file):

```
import traceback
import sys

# hopefully the only external package I need
from gribapi import *

# file with all possible 'messages'
INPUT = '2015121406_gfs.t06z.pgrb2.0p25.f000'
VERBOSE=1 # verbose error reporting

def example():
    f = open(INPUT)

    # location we are interested in
    lat, lon = 64.1353, -21.8952

    while 1:
        # STEP 1:
        # open downloaded GRIB2 file
        gid = grib_new_from_file(f)
        if gid is None: break

        # define the iterator (which is throughout the program the same?)
        iterid = grib_iterator_new(gid,0)

        # get the result for the nearest location
        nearest = grib_find_nearest(gid, lat, lon)[0]

        while 1:
            # STEP 2:
            # ???
            #
            # the loop goes through the whole file
            # instead just selecting messages we need beforehand...
            # fictional function which selects
            # 'TMP' (temperature) on 'surface' messages only
            # without need to iterate all of them:
            # 
            # result = grib_select_specific_message(gid, 'TMP', 'surface')

            result = grib_iterator_next(iterid)
            if not result: break

        # STEP 3:
        # profit!
        # result variable returns numbers which I process in any way I need, yay!

        # more undocumented stuff,
        # put here just because examples do it the same way
        grib_iterator_delete(iterid)
        grib_release(gid)

    f.close()

# main program function
def main():
    try:
        example()
    except GribInternalError,err:
        if VERBOSE:
            traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stderr)
        else:
            print >>sys.stderr,err.msg

        return 1

# run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

The problem with this code is that it iterates trough the whole file, all the messages and all possible coordinates (whole planet, 0.25 degrees precision). If file is 300+ MB it takes *a while* to read it. I feel like using "iterator" here (whatever that is) is a bit wrong since I need to "cherry-pick" only specific information (few weather parameters for a particular location only) and `grib_find_nearest()` function doesn't need an iterator at all to select only part of the data.
This could be half-solved with filtering the data I need *before* downloading the file (results in much smaller file) but I'm still not sure how to do it (part of [Downloading GRIB GFS files with specific filters?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/173773/downloading-grib-files-with-specific-filters)), but still I'd like to figure this out since it might happen that I will occasionally have to download "full" files.

Comment: I am trying to extract variables in grib using pygrib such as 'Temperature','Relative humidity','U component of wind','V component of wind' and save this extracted variables with another grib file name. How can I do that please help me out.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/157930)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/157930)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I eventually ended up with ditching [gribapi](https://software.ecmwf.int/wiki/display/GRIB/GRIB+API+examples) and switching to [Met Office's Iris](http://scitools.org.uk/iris/docs/latest/index.html) Python package which solves my problem in a very elegant way. Although it was a bit of a pain to install it (dependencies could be really tricky) at least the documentation is good and it is really easy to use it.

Answer (score 6):

Another idea would be to use pygrib module:

```py
    import pygrib

    grbs= pygrib.open("my_file.grb")

    # use grbs.select to select the grids you are interested in (shortName, typeOfLevel, level=500, marsParam, dataDate, dataTime, ...)

    DATA=np.array(grbs.select(marsParam=my_param,dataDate=my_date,dataTime=my_time))

    # DATA will contain 3 arrays
    # DATA[0] for values
    # DATA[1] for longitudes
    # DATA[2] for latitudes

    # from the "values" array, extract in lon and lat
    DATA1=DATA[0].data(lat1=my_y1,lat2=my_y2,lon1=my_x1,lon2=my_x2))
```

Comment: What is `my_param` here?

Answer (score 0):

Using `pygrib` was eventually easy once I figured out the `keys()` of the .grib file I had. *One thing I noticed is that the **keys** which have specific data are the same keys I used in the API query to download the weather data.*

I downloaded my data from the [Climate Data Store](https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/cdsapp#!/home) and the [**ECMWF parameter database**](https://apps.ecmwf.int/codes/grib/param-db) is a good source to **see parameter names** (the names of the parameters are slightly different than that used to pass through the API query).

```
wash_2014_grib = "Washington2014Data.grib" # Local downloaded grib file
grbs = pygrib.open(wash_2014_grib)

grb = grbs.select(name="2 metre temperature",year=2014,month=5,day=1,time=500)[0]
temporal_data = grb.values
```

The above will extract 2 m temperature data for May 1, 2014 at 5:00. (Note that the `.select` method of `pygrib` does *not permit leading zeros in decimal integer literals*. Without calling the zeroeth index (`[0]`), it returns a list of `pygribmessage`s, which can be accessed iteratively or simply by calling the index.

In the above output, grb is a `pygribmessage` object and `temporal_data` is an array of values of temperatures at every coordinate.

To extract specific coordinate data,

```
y1,y2,x1,x2 = 46,46.5,-120.5,-120
local_data,lats,lons = grb.data(lat1=y1,lat2=y2,lon1=x1,lon2=x2)
```

which gives

```
>>> local_data
array([[287.25024414, 289.18969727, 292.21118164],
       [290.43579102, 293.13500977, 292.69360352],
       [285.51391602, 288.09790039, 291.69165039]])
>>> lats
array([[46.5 , 46.5 , 46.5 ],
       [46.25, 46.25, 46.25],
       [46.  , 46.  , 46.  ]])
>>> lons
array([[-120.5 , -120.25, -120.  ],
       [-120.5 , -120.25, -120.  ],
       [-120.5 , -120.25, -120.  ]])
```

All set for further analysis!

Answer (score 0):

Try using [xarray](https://xarray.dev/) with [cfgrib](https://github.com/ecmwf/cfgrib) (these can be installed via pip or conda).

See the [GRIB Data Example](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/examples/ERA5-GRIB-example.html) to view and extract data from an [example file](https://github.com/pydata/xarray-data/blob/master/era5-2mt-2019-03-uk.grib).

```
import xarray as xr

ds = xr.open_dataset("path/to/era5-2mt-2019-03-uk.grib", engine="cfgrib")

# extract a timeseries from a coordinate
ds.t2m.sel(longitude=0, latitude=51.5)
```